# How can I git fetch/pull an outdated unchanged branch with one command?

Tags: git, merge, fetch

Ok let's say we have a main branch called `MAIN`.

Let's say I create a local branch called 100.

Later on, someone creates a local branch on their own machine called 101.

Later on, they make changes to their local 101 branch, and then merge the changes back into `MAIN`.

Later on, I decide I'm finally ready to make some changes on 100.
However, I know MAIN has since changed. I want to make a one line git statement to update my local 100 branch with what's in `MAIN`.

Is there one?

Typically, I would do the following series of steps

```
git checkout MAIN
git pull
git checkout 100
git merge MAIN
```

How can I combine these series of steps into 1 command to pull the `MAIN's` branch into my local 100 branch (that contains no changes at the moment)?

Comment: Why one command mate?

Comment: The same way as you run multiple UNIX commands in a single line. Check the && ; || in unix

Comment: Just make your 100 branch track MAIN and then use `git pull` whenever you want to update?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the number of commands, but there are a series of distinct steps that you cannot skip, and which make *no sense* to combine:

- select branch
- fetch origin
- merge changes

Git provides no magic single method for doing these three distinct and unrelated operations. The closest you're going to get is to either write your own higher-level command, or just do the three commands in one lin:

```
git checkout 100 && git fetch && git merge origin/MAIN
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Single line command

You can always use `;`; as delimter in ordet to use single line

```
git checkout 100; git fetch --all--prune; git pull origin MAIN
```

As a best practice you should always use the branch name you wish to pull/merge. Only in git v2.0 the matching value was updated form `simple` to `matching` so it will not push all your branches to the remote.

#### Git alias

You can always set up alias which will get paramters and place them when needed.

For example: (inside you ~/.gitconfig add this line)

```
[alias] 
    myalias = !git checkout 100 && git fetch --all --prune && git pull origin MAIN
```

Comment: I think your alias is wrong. Should be more like: `!f() { git checkout 100; ... }; f`